# How do you source a file (i.e. gist) in bash?

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I want to source a gist into my bash shell, how do I do this in one line? In other words, I do not want to create an intermediate file.

I tried this, but it fails to source the remote file:

```
source <(curl -s -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash)
```

Running on Mac OSX 10.9.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The command you listed works for me. Have you tried running just the curl command alone to make sure you can download that file appropriately?

Comment: Yes, the curl works and that command runs just fine. However, after you run it, do you actually have git completion? If you run `type __git_complete` after sourcing that command, what do you see? Assuming you do not already have git completion sourced.

Comment: Yeah, I had been using Bash 4, on both Linux and OS X, when I tried it. I've added an answer that gives you a few options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple ships an ancient version of Bash, Bash 3.2; Bash 4 was released 5 years ago. Here are a few possible ways to work around this:

1. Install [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/), [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), or [pkgsrc](https://www.pkgsrc.org/) and install Bash via one of them; or just [build and install it yourself from source](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/). Remember to add your newly installed bash to `/etc/shells` so you can set it as your shell, then go to "System Preferences > Users and Groups", click the lock to supply your password so you can make changes, then right click (two-finger click/control click) on your user to choose "Advanced Options..." and change your shell there.
2. If you must be compatible with the 7 year old Bash shipped on OS X, you could just save the file and source it from there. Here's an example Bash function to make that easier:

   ```
   function curlsource() {
       f=$(mktemp -t curlsource)
       curl -o "$f" -s -L "$1"
       source "$f"
       rm -f "$f"
   }
   curlsource https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
   ```
3. If you absolutely must avoid even creating a temporary file, and must run on ancient versions of Bash, the best you can do is read into a string and eval the result. I tried to emulate the effect of `source <(cmd)` by creating a FIFO (named pipe), piping the output of `cmd` into it, and reading it with `source`, but got nothing. It turns out, taking a look at the source for Bash 3.2, `source` simply reads the whole file into a string, and it checks the file size before doing so. A FIFO returns a size of 0 when you `stat` it, so `source` happily allocates a string of length 1 (for the trailing null), reads 0 bytes into it, and returns success. So, since `source` is just reading the whole file into a string and then evaluating that, you can just do the same:

   ```
   eval "$(curl -s -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash)"
   ```

Comment: I'm pinned to the old stuff for some of my servers but the eval works great. Thanks Brian

Comment: @MikeD Yep, I figured you might not be able to update, so decided to give a few different options. I had done #2 on my Mac so long ago that I'd forgotten I'd done it, which was why I posted the original "works for me" comment. Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

OS X still ships `bash` 3.2 by default; in that version, the `source` command does not seem to work properly with process substitutions, as can be demonstrated with a simple test:

```
$ source <(echo FOO=5)
$ echo $FOO

$
```

The same `source` command does, however, work in `bash` 4.1 or later (I don't have a 4.0 installation to test, and the release notes seem to be silent on the matter.)

Comment: You can, BTW also see from where the script is sourced with `source <(echo 'echo $BASH_SOURCE')`. I am not sure if it is using temp files in all cases, bash 4.3.24 on FreeBSD9 does print `/tmp//sh-np-425112718` (even when /dev/fd is mounted).

Comment: that is good info. i just tested your code and mine in centos6.5 running bash4.1 and it worked. still need something for bash3.2 but thank you.

Answer (score -2):

This will work on any version of bash and without any file creation.

```
source <<< "$(curl -s -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash)"
```